# iphone: Kal calendar not running in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios5

I have downloaded demo for `Kal calendar` from [source code API at github](http://github.com/klazuka/Kal%20objective-c%20xcode%20iphone-sdk-4.0) and try running demo code in my xcode4.2 but it just builds not running it.

I want to try it out with enabling/disabling dates into it and all other operations.

It is not giving any warning or errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you gone through the integration steps as given with it?

**Integrating Kal into Your Project - XCode prior than 4**

Kal is compiled as a static library, and the recommended way to add it to your project is to use Xcode's "dependent project" facilities by following these step-by-step instructions:

1. Clone the Kal git repository: git clone git://github.com/klazuka/Kal.git. Make sure you store the repository in a permanent place because Xcode will need to reference the files every time you compile your project.
2. Locate the "Kal.xcodeproj" file under "Kal/src/". Drag Kal.xcodeproj and drop it onto the root of your Xcode project's "Groups and Files" sidebar. A dialog will appear -- make sure "Copy items" is unchecked and "Reference Type" is "Relative to Project" before clicking "Add".
3. Now you need to link the Kal static library to your project. Select the Kal.xcodeproj file that you just added to the sidebar. Under the "Details" table, you will see libKal.a. Check the checkbox on the far right for this file. This will tell Xcode to link against Kal when building your app.
4. Now you need to add Kal as a dependency of your project so that Xcode will compile it whenever you compile your project. Expand the "Targets" section of the sidebar and double-click your application's target. Under the "General" tab you will see a "Direct Dependencies" section. Click the "+" button, select "Kal" and click "Add Target".
5. Now you need to add the bundle of image resources internally used by Kal's UI. Locate "Kal.bundle" under "Kal/src" and drag and drop it into your project. A dialog will appear -- make sure "Create Folder References" is selected, "Copy items" is unchecked, and "Reference Type" is "Relative to Project" before clicking "Add".
6. Finally, we need to tell your project where to find the Kal headers. Open your "Project Settings" and go to the "Build" tab. Look for "Header Search Paths" and double-click it. Add the relative path from your project's directory to the "Kal/src" directory.
7. While you are in Project Settings, go to "Other Linker Flags" under the "Linker" section, and add "-all_load" to the list of flags.
8. You're ready to go. Just #import "Kal.h" anywhere you want to use KalViewController in your project.

I have recently integrated this calendar and its working fine at my side.

**Integrating Kal into Your Project - XCode 4**

In XCode 4 it works a lil bit different then before.

First of all before using a static library you need to understand how this stuff is integrated.
A very good introduction is given by clint harris at: [**Easy, Modular Code Sharing Across iPhone Apps: Static Libraries and Cross-Project References**](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/)
I recommend you to read his guide. After that many things are more clear.

1. To get the Kal library into your project forget the old guide for XCode 3.
   In XCode 4 click on your project in the project navigator. Say add files to project and find the Kal.xcodeproj. file and add it.When you see the Kal Project under your project you are almost there.
2. Now again select your project in the project navigator and go to build settings. there search for "Linker" and fill in Other Linker Flags: "-Objc and -all_load", also insert the path to the Kal directory in the Library Search Paths and the relative path from your project to the kal project under: "Header Search Paths".
   Thats it for Build settings.
3. Now go to Build Phases:
   Add the Kal static library to the target dependencies, also add the libKal.a to Link Binary with Libraries and at the end add the Kal.bundle to "Copy Bundle Resources".

Comment: I am using xcode4.2 and i am not able to find "general" tab as per point-4 and "detail" table as per point-3

Comment: all the points i have covered other than 3rd.but still when i #import"Kal.h" it shows errors as "Kal.h file not found" and not able to find libKal.a file while adding 'link binary with libraries'

Comment: Have you added target dependencies? General tab is available as "Build Phases" in XCode 4.2. As you select target, it will be there as one of the tab on right side.

Comment: I have added Kal as target dependencies to my native project

Comment: I am not able to find about 3rd step.4th i have done.also added libkal.a

Comment: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/ will help you.

Comment: As per the article,set 'user header search path' and 'other linker flags' but still it is showing that error 'file not found'

Comment: as soon as i removed '-all_load','-ObjC' from other linker flags errors disappeared

Comment: @heena: I have inserted detailed and easy way to integrate static library and references with XCode 4.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a similar API: tapkulibrary : https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

I solved the problem with this tutorial:

http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=657

I solved the problem in the step:

Next, we need to tell your project where to find the TapkuLibrary headers. Select the target, then Build Settings. Search for ‘Header Search Paths’ and double-click it to add the path to the Tapku lib. So add ‘$(SRCROOT)/Coverflow/Tapku/src’ and click ‘Done’.
N.B – Make sure the path is correct based on your project name, so replace ‘Coverflow’ in the path above with your project name.

I think, that the problem is similar. So you need to point where is the headers in the target, in the option: Header Search Paths

I hope to be useful